# WCF service hosted in windows service - Performance issue

Tags: performance, wcf, windows-services

From a website I am calling this WCF services which is hosted in Windows service environment. If multiple calls are made to this service concurrently from the website, Will it cause any performance issue?

In my case all the logged in users in the website can call the WCF service which is hosted in windows service. And the WCF service is a long running task.

I hope the service will by default use thread from the thread pool to handle each request (request to the service from website) if it defined as "For PerCall services". But my doubt is since it is a long running task (hours to finish), will it cause thread pool starvation when multiple user request for the service?

Thanks

Comment: There are multiple settings (and coding practices) that determine the scalability and performance of a WCF service. Not all related to WCF itself, of course, but also to your actual implementation logic. Now, are you having an actual performance issue (then include the relevant information), or are you just asking a "could I potentially have"-question. The later is impossible to answer without more detailed information.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Mine is "could I potentially have" Question. The problem is my tasks(wcf) are long running. Will take hours to finish. And the question is WCF hosted in windows service and number of concurrent request to that WCF service will cause any performance issue? OR I should use any other approach for long running task implementation?